# Objects Detection on AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone knows a good library that makes objects detection in AS3?
Im looking for something similar to detect an hand, like kinectic.

Comment: You mean object detection with a webcam?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3027

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I can think of, although I think it is mainly for faces but perhaps with some tweaking or something could be used for a hand.

http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=416